# How to make controller to work in a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

i am working with angularjs.The problem is that i wrote a controller in directive after a compile function and the output through the compile function is shown as that in the pic. i.e "first in the compile". but the output from the controller is not showing and it's showing an error and the error is displayed in the image i have posted. please help me with this.
am sending the code

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   
    $scope.emp = [{ name: "Day", age: "25", salary: "30000", place: "sydney", color: "#FF5733" },
        { name: "Dickinson", age: "34", salary: "6000", place: "disney", color: "#FAB304" },
        { name: "Domeyko", age: "27", salary: "9000", place: "newyork", color: "#0ED1B3" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#896BBB" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#387037" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#F3AE1B" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#FAB304" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#D10E7B" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#0EC8D1" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#FFC300  " },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#D10E5B" },
        { name: "Echols", age: "25", salary: "15000", place: "sweden", color: "#13D0E1" }];
}]);
app.directive('showDetails', function ($interpolate) {
    return {
        //templateUrl: 'showDetails.html'
        compile: function (tElement, tAttributes) {
            console.log(tAttributes.text + "-in compile");
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attri) {
            var v = $interpolate($attri.text)($scope);
            //console.log($attri.text + "-in controller");
            console.log(v + "-in controller");
        }
    }
     
});
```

```html
 <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ChildCtrl.js"></script>
    
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

   
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('../images/uRzTkNW.jpg');" ng-controller="ctrl">
   
    <div ng-repeat="emps in emp" class="col-md-3">
        <div show-details text="first">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post. The 'pic' you mention isn't even included in the post but if it were a picture of your code is of little use in helping you.

Comment: hi, while am trying to upload an image it showing that i cant add image instead they made it as link.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBP9.png [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBNIK.png. here one picture is output where error is displayed. and the next picture is directive code.

Comment: and as I wrote, that image is of no use unless you also post your code in the question. Also have you even tried clicking on the URL included in the error message (I can't because it's only an image)? Usually those links in angular error messages give very helpful information.

Comment: how to add the code bro, help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
controller: function ($scope, $element, $attri) {
```

If you click on the link given in the error message it probably explains all this, but the problem is you are trying to inject a service called `$attri` into your controller but there is no angular service of that name: you probably wanted `$attrs`. `$scope`, `$element`, `$attrs`, `$transclude` are all available to inject into a controller as are other angular services.

Comment: i have seen in a tutorial in youtube bro  (custom directives in angularjs by techcbt). he got the result. and i cannot understand what the problem with mine.

Comment: I corrected my answer, short version: you misspelled `$attrs`